# ModSecurity compile error on nginx

Tags: nginx, centos6, mod-security

I'm trying to install ModSecurity on nginx with the following instructions :

```
wget https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/archive/master.zip
unzip master
cd ModSecurity-master
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-standalone-module
```

And i got the following error :

```
Checking plataform... Identified as Linux
configure: looking for Apache module support via DSO through APXS
configure: error: couldn't find APXS
```

After installing httpd-devel and executing `./configure --enable-standalone-module --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs ; make` modsecurity compile workes but still have another error of nginx compilation :

`./configure --add-module=/usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity` and i got this error :

```
    gcc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g   -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I /usr/include/apache2 -I /usr/include/apr-1.0 -I /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone -I /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2 -I /usr/include/libxml2 -I objs -I src/http -I src/http/modules -I src/mail \
            -o objs/addon/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.o \
            /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:20:23: error: http_core.h: No such file or directory
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:21:26: error: http_request.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:37,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_logging.h:41:23: error: apr_pools.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:38,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_multipart.h:26:25: error: apr_general.h: No such file or directory
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_multipart.h:27:24: error: apr_tables.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:38,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_multipart.h:44: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_array_header_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_multipart.h:65: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_array_header_t’
    cc1: warnings being treated as errors
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_multipart.h:135: error: data definition has no type or storage class
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_multipart.h:135: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘apr_status_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_multipart.h:135: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘multipart_cleanup’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_multipart.h:137: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_table_t’
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:39,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_pcre.h:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:32: error: data definition has no type or storage class
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:36: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘APR_DECLARE_OPTIONAL_FN’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:37: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘modsec_register_reqbody_processor’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:37: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:37: error: data definition has no type or storage class
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:37: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘APR_DECLARE_OPTIONAL_FN’
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:42,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:29,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:40,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:65: error: data definition has no type or storage class
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:93: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/apache2.h:95: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:29,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:40,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:43:25: error: http_config.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:29,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:40,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:59: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_array_header_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:61: error: data definition has no type or storage class
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:61: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘apr_status_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:61: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘collection_original_setvar’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:63: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_pool_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:67: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:70: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:75: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_array_header_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:76: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_pool_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:86: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_pool_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:94: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:101: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_pool_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:111: error: data definition has no type or storage class
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:111: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘apr_status_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:149: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_array_header_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:189: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:219: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:235: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘fn_tfn_execute_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:239: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fn_tfn_execute_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:258: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_table_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:258: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_pool_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:285: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_table_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:341: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:341: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘apr_status_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:341: error: ‘apr_status_t’ declared as function returning a function
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:341: error: ‘apr_status_t’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:113: note: previous declaration of ‘apr_status_t’ was here
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:342: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_pool_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:342: error: ‘fn_action_execute_t’ declared as function returning a function
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:369: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘fn_action_init_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:399: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:403: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_array_header_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:403: error: ‘msre_parse_vars’ declared as function returning a function
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/re.h:415: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_size_t’
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:40,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:54: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:62: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:68: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:70: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:74: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:76: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:82: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:88: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:140: error: data definition has no type or storage class
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:140: error: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘apr_fileperms_t’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:140: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘mode2fileperms’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_util.h:144: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘apr_pool_t’
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:41,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_xml.h:43: error: ‘xml_cleanup’ declared as function returning a function
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:42,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_geo.h:38:25: error: apr_file_io.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:42,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_geo.h:58: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_file_t’
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:43,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_gsb.h:22:22: error: apr_hash.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:43,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_gsb.h:25: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_file_t’
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:44,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_unicode.h:25: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘apr_file_t’
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:46,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/msc_crypt.h:34: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
    In file included from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../standalone/api.h:23,
                     from /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:28:
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:48:23: error: ap_config.h: No such file or directory
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:49:21: error: apr_md5.h: No such file or directory
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:50:25: error: apr_strings.h: No such file or directory
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/../../apache2/modsecurity.h:54:22: error: http_log.h: No such file or directory
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:938: error: ‘ngx_http_modsecurity_ctx_t’ has no member named ‘req’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:938: error: too many arguments to function ‘ConvertNgxStringToUTF8’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:942: error: ‘ngx_http_modsecurity_ctx_t’ has no member named ‘req’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:944: error: ‘ngx_http_modsecurity_ctx_t’ has no member named ‘req’
    /usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.c:952: error: ‘modsecurity_read_body_cb’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    make[1]: *** [objs/addon/modsecurity/ngx_http_modsecurity.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/john/nginx-1.2.5'
    make: *** [build] Error 2
```

**Note : I'm using nginx as the only webserver and i do not have apache installed.**

**OS : Centos 6 64bit**

How can i solve this problem And do you have another easy way to install modsecurity with nginx ?

Comment: The system has automatically flagged this post as too long, the maximum length being 30k characters. In general, only the very beginning or the very end (or both) of this type of message is useful and you appear to be missing the end. Please reduce the size of your message and include only the relevant details.

Comment: @lain I deleted too many characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the package httpd-devel. It contains the apxs tool needed by the configure script.

Comment: I have installed httpd-devel and i did `./configure --enable-standalone-module --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs ; make` .. But i'm still receiving the error of `./configure --add-module=/usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it need the apx library to build the standalone module. I think on CentOS you ineed to install **httpd-devel**

Comment: I have installed httpd-devel and i did `./configure --enable-standalone-module --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs ; make` .. But i'm still receiving the error of `./configure --add-module=/usr/local/src/john/ModSecurity-master/nginx/modsecurity`

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on **Ubuntu 16.04** with latest version of **Modsecurity 2.9.1** and **Nginx 1.10.2**. After googling I solved this just by installing `apache2-dev`.
`apt-get install apache2-dev`